# CSS active with ID and CLASS

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I code this CSS using `class="active"` so that the background will show below it? Using a different color on `.active`, so to speak (not `:hover`).

```
<a href="[url]" id="curs_section" class="active">kids</a>
```

My attempt:

```
a#curs_section .active  {
    background-color: #66a7eb; 
    color: #333; 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not have space before `.active` as it is class on the anchor itself. `a#curs_section .active` means element with class `active` which is a descendant of `a#curs_section`, hence your style was not getting applied.

```
a#curs_section.active  {
    background-color: #66a7eb; 
    color: #333; 
}
```

Comment: OMG, haha! Thanks so much! Feel even more stupid now... the only option I didn't try..pfff!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

take out the space:

```
a#curs_section .active  {
              ^---
```

with the space, it's an `<a>` element with curs_section ID, followed by some **OTHER** element with a `.active` class.

Without the space:

```
a#curs_section.active  {
```

it's an `<a>` which has id curs_section AND the .active class.